# How to ensure method in ActiveX class gets into DLL (Checking by ITypeLib)

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, com, activex

In Visual Studio 2013, how do we ensure that the methods added in the ActiveX is accessible in Javascript and can be viewed in OlleView's `ITypeLib`

I have this method that would not show in the `ITypeLib` in OlleView but there methods are showing:

```
public:
    STDMETHOD(SendToREST)(BSTR resource, BSTR operation, BSTR data); // not showing
    STDMETHOD(WriteBuf)(/*[in]*/ BSTR a); // showing
```

I've been doing `regsvr32` registration of the DLL but still the method is not showing up.

- What can I use to trace why method is not showing up?
- Is it because the method is not really in the DLL or some registry is
  not updated?
- Should I manually add it to the Project's IDL file? (because I cannot see it there)

Comment: The 3rd bullet is the problem.  You need to do this the other way around, *first* add it to the IDL and *then* ensure that the compiler complains because you did not add the method yet.  In VS2013 always use the class wizard so both things happen at the same time.

Comment: @HansPassant what if the class (.h and .cpp) is already there should I add the class again (in reference to the Class Wizard you are saying)?

Comment: @HansPassant you comment work, you can put it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the methods in question to interface in the IDL. Then those interfaces should be either in library block there, or referenced by anything from library block. This is necessary for these IDL definitions to get compiled into type library. Then make sure the type library is registered.

C++ code will reference the derivative of the IDL and your classes will override the abstract virtual methods defined in IDL interfaces. This is how C++ code is connected with type library definitions.

Comment: How do I make sure the the type library is registered, is the regsvr32 command not enough?

Comment: `regsvr32` is OK when type library is a part of DLL. You can always double check by opening with OleView, when you look up your type library by its LIBID (as opposed to browsing for a specific file).